# How do I automatically keep all locally installed Chocolatey packages up to date?

Tags: chocolatey

There is [Ketarin](http://ketarin.org/) to update Chocolatey packages and push them to chocolatey.org automatically, but how do I automatically update all locally installed Chocolatey packages?

Comment: Schedule `cup all`? https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CommandsUpdate

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try `choco upgrade all -y`. One can create a scheduled task to run in the evenings that would do this.

Comment: We have also discussed that we would make this a feature of ChocolateyGUI, but as yet, we have not had a chance to include this.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark Would be nice to have that feature in the ChocolateyGUI!

Comment: Sometimes updating packages hits an error that requires manual intervention. Would a scheduled task report that?

Comment: It would be in the log @CarlWalsh but without something like growl hooked up it would not report it.

Comment: Thanks @ferventcoder and congrats to the first 10K;)

Answer (score 19):

Update - Sept 2018

As well as [choco-upgrade-all-at-startup](https://chocolatey.org/packages/choco-upgrade-all-at-startup) to upgrade all packages on startup (mentioned above), there is also now a Chocolatey package, [choco-upgrade-all-at](https://chocolatey.org/packages/choco-upgrade-all-at), that can be used to check/upgrade all packages as often (for example, daily, weekly..) as you require, at a time that suits :-)

A downside of using the public repository of course is that you are dependent on other people to maintain the packages largely out of the goodness of their hearts, so you should probably still run something like SUMo once in a while to keep an eye on things if you are using this to keep your own machines up-to-date. Organisations are strongly encouraged to host and maintain their own repository rather than use the public one for this reason.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the [choco-upgrade-all-at-startup](https://chocolatey.org/packages/choco-upgrade-all-at-startup) package by issuing:

```
choco install choco-upgrade-all-at-startup -y
```

Once the installation is complete, a scheduled task has been created that upgrades all packages when the computer boots. Note: if one uses a laptop, please ensure that this is on AC power. Otherwise the scheduled task will not be run and the chocolatey packages will not be updated.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** this answer was relevant for some quite old version of Chocolatey (0.9.8 and older).

You should be aware that `Chocolatey` in fact **doesn't update already installed packages** (neither `cup all` or `cup <package>`), but rather **installs a newer version(s) beside older one(s)**. So you'll end up with a stack of previously installed versions of a package(s) on your system. And there is currently no way to uninstall the specific version of the package except the most recent one using `Chocolatey`.

**UPDATE:** according to [@ferventcoder's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579193/how-to-automatically-keep-all-locally-installed-chocolatey-packages-up-to-date/26870291?noredirect=1#comment47150117_26870291), *Chocolatey* of version **0.9.9+** does a real update now! This is huge improvement actually. Versions 0.9.8 and bellow do just an install as described earlier. See [release notes](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/ReleaseNotes) for details about new C# client.

Comment: Sadly you can't. See [uninstall command description](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CommandsUninstall). `version` argument is ignored and *Chocolatey* removes the most recent version. Tested using version `0.9.8.28`.

Comment: It seems the uninstall command is particularly unusable in this case. :/

Comment: @ferventcoder Exactly. Actually whole *Chocolatey* seems to be unusable to me. I mean the client. Repository alone is great, but there is a lot of similar repositories on the internets. I have described my disappointment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870648/proper-using-of-chocolatey-package-update-version-management/26879253). I hope new C# client will solve this issues.

Comment: @ferventcoder Oh, you already have read it, since you answer to that question :)

Comment: We can edit this question now to state that 0.9.9+ does do this and 0.9.8 and below don't do this.

Comment: @ferventcoder Nice! Should I test it or can I trust you? :)

Answer (score 3):

For `choco` v0.10.1+, use:

```
choco upgrade
```

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsUpgrade

From v1.0.0 `choco update` is deprecated:

```
DEPRECATION NOTICE - choco update is deprecated and will be removed or
 replaced in version 1.0.0 with something that performs the functions
 of updating package indexes. Please use `choco upgrade` instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cup all -y
```

or

```
chocolatey update all -y
```

Comment: DEPRECATION NOTICE - choco update is deprecated and will be removed or replaced in version 1.0.0 with something that performs the functions of updating package indexes. Please use `choco upgrade` instead.